# documentation beta approving all or nothing

Tags: discussion, documentation

So when somebody adds a new topic and has multiple Examples, you're asked to approve or reject the topic.

My issue is that maybe one section is written well, but the other example not. Wouldn't it make more sense to approve the part that is okay and the topic, but reject the rest?

At the moment it is all or nothing.

Comment: I agree, it happened to me several times